# Sibling selector on image wrapped with links

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to sibling-select images. There's a sequence of images that are wrapped with links and I want to select all but the first one.

```
img {
    max-width: 50px;
}
.content img {
    max-width: 400px;
}
img.a ~ img.a {
    border: 1px #333 solid;
}
```

---

```
<div class="content">
    <a href="/">
        <img class="a b c" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6d/Astrodon1DB.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="/">
        <img class="a b c" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Nipponosaurus_dinosaur.png">
    </a>
    <a href="/">
        <img class="a b c" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/28/Macronaria_scrubbed_enh.jpg/800px-Macronaria_scrubbed_enh.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/efsev59z/

Why doesn't `img.a ~ img.a` select all images with class "a" that follows an image with class "a"? From my understanding they're both children of a common element, `.content`. What's wrong, and how do I make it happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be considered siblings, the elements need to be children of the same *immediate* parent (not just a common ancestor, since all DOM elements share `body` as an ancestor for example). Consider something like this:

```
a ~ a > img.a {
    /* styles */
}
```

Comment: I see! I think I confused children with descendant. Also I didn't realise you could combine combinators like that, it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

sibling selectors only apply to siblings. Each one of those images have their own parents. They are cousins, rather than siblings.

Comment: Is it a thing, _really_?)

Comment: More specifically, there's no nibling (nephew/niece) selector.

Comment: Is there a way I can indicate the entire "a > img" (link with image inside it) object with css?

Comment: See Don's answer, I think its what you're trying to do. Also, if you simply don't want to match the first one, you could do 
```
a:nth-child(n+2) img.a {
    border: 1px #333 solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to apply the border to all images but then override it for the first image. You can use the `:first-child` selector to get the first anchor and target the image within it.

```
img {
    max-width: 50px;
}
.content img {
    max-width: 400px;
}
img.a  {
    border: 1px #333 solid;
}
.content a:first-child img {
    border:none;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/efsev59z/4/